# React - Setting up "add to cart"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a little project here, a clothing website. I have never been able to set up "add to cart" feature on past websites due to lack of experience. But that was a while ago, I have decided to give this another shot.

Now, I got stuck pretty fast and generally just need some guidance and tips on how I should setup this.

So far, I have made the "add to cart" button send back the data, such as name, price, color, image to the parent component.

The folder for the "product page" where the "add to cart" button is located looks like this:

```
./Product
  ./productFetch
     // API Fetch files
  ./Product.js // Parent
  ./ProductContent.js // Child | Also where "add to cart" btn is located
```

Now, the actual cart component is located in a separate folder, like this:

```
./Components
    ./product
      // ...
    ./ShoppingCart
      ./Cart.js // Parent
      ./Product.js // Child (the "card" for each product)
```

So far, as mentioned. The information I need in Cart.js, has been sent to `Product.js` inside of `./Product`. But now I need to send it to `Cart.js` inside of `./ShoppingCart`.

How should I tackle this? I tried to use LocalStorage for this, but no luck there. I have watched some tutorials but well firstly, they arent in the same scenario as me. And also, I don't really follow along what is going on.

Pretty much the issue I am having is, how can I efficiently send over the data of a product to the Cart when the "add to cart" button is clicked.

I could of course send the data back to `App.js`, and then send it to cart. But then I would be lifting the state up twice, and then giving it to `Cart.js`. And as I have understood, you are not supposed to do this.

Not sure what code is needed, let me know what code you need to help me out!

Thanks.

*Edit:*
Here is parts of the code that might be useful:

"Add To Cart" button inside of `./ProductContent.js`

```
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() =>
              props.addToCart({
                name: props.name,
                price: props.price,
                color: props.mainImg?.colour,
                img: props.mainImg?.url,
                id: params.productid,
              })
            }
            className={classes.add_to_cart}
          >
            <Cart />
            add to cart
          </button>
```

Parent to `./ProductContent.js`:

```
  const [addCart, addToCart] = useState();

  console.log(addCart);   
   <ProductContent
        name={props.name}
        price={props.price}
        brandName={props.brandName}
        media={props.media}
        catWalk={props.catWalk}
        mainImg={props.mainImg}
        sizes={props.sizes}
        categoryType={props.categoryType}
        addToCart={(addCart) => addToCart(addCart)}
      />
```

Comment: As far as I understand, this is a state management issue which can be solved with either Context Api or Redux. Have you tried to implement one of these? These tools are for this type of problems.

Comment: I have looked into Context API in the past, but it has always confused me. I'll see if I can make anything work with it and I will also take a look at Redux!

Comment: in my opinion, setting up context is easier and more comfortable than setting up redux. Also for your project, it should work fine and is a great practice for your skills.

Comment: Alright awesome. I'll check it out and see if I can get anything to work! Thanks